# How to stretch the image from one screen to two screens

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I want to be able to stretch the image from one monitor to a second monitor even if i have to use some software to do it.

For example i want the top half of the image that is now shown on my first monitor to occupy the whole second monitor and i want the bottom half to occupy the whole first monitor, or the other way around i don't really care as long as it works.
I would be cool to know how to do the same stuff but to the left half and right half.

I know that image pixels would have twice the lenght or height this way but i don't really care about it as long as it works so basically i want the stuff to show on both monitors but with the same pixels as before.

I have a hd4870 and windows7 and hd4000 family doesnt support having two monitors behaving like a large one, only hd5000 upwards, this would solve my problems without any of the drawbacks but it just can't be done (or maybe it can via software but i'm just too tired of searching).

A solution to make almost any graphic card have two monitors behaving like a large one is matrox dualhead2go but that's just as expensive as a good hd5000 card so it's not worth it.

thanks in advance

### EDIT

I guess that nobody so far was able to fully comprehend my problem that was very explicitly written but i will elaborate some more.

My hd4870 can have 2 monitors working with it but some stuff like games won't run on both monitors, which sucks.

There are some ways to circumvent this problem and two of them are perfect or almost perfect but expensive and the third would be a software solution that would make it possible.

The first one is to have and hd5000 family video card which will work just fine with both monitors.

The second is to have a matrox dualhead2go that will make my hd4870 detect my two monitors as a large monitor.

The third is to have a software that makes my two displays be detected as a large display and then captures the output of the video card, splits the images and renders them as 2d images to both monitors OR a simpler one but that would make outputted pixels double the width or height would be to capture the output of the graphics card to one screen, split it in two and enlarge it to fit both monitors and then output it to the monitors.

p.s. By capturing the output of the video card i mean just make the video card process the stuff in a certain way. Making the video card detect two monitors as a large one via software may be a bit impossible or impracticable but stretching the output as a 2d image from one to both monitors for some coders should be a walk in the park so it would be likely that such program would exist or that some widespread softwares for dual monitor would have such function in them.

Comment: No idea why you got the downvote. . .

Comment: @surfasb neither do i, maybe the downvoter wants 2 monitors but for some reason he can't or something, go figure -.-'

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how Eyefinity work. But on a 4870, you'll need to use software like UltraMon, which will maximize windows across monitors.

Googling brought up [Virtaul Screen Maximizer](http://virtualscreenmaximizer.en.softonic.com/) who's sole purpose is to allow you to maximize a Window across multiple displays.

**Bonus chatter:**
This feature use to exist and was called **Spanning** under Windows XP. When Microsoft moved to the new WDM driver model, that feature was no longer available.

**edit:**

Ultramon has this functionality, but not builtin.  On Ultramon's website is a [scripting](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/scripts/) section with this: Maximize2Mon. It is a VBScript that uses Ultramon to get the properties of both monitors and then resizes the Window to both monitors.

I use Displayfusion currently, but originally I recalled a hotkey setting on Ultramon that maximized windows to multiple monitors. My memory is playing games with me.

Comment: I already use ultramon and it doesn't do exactly one or the other stuff i want. I will check that screen maximiser thing. Some people that use two monitors sometimes have the problem of the image from being stretched occupying both, that isn't a problem to me as at least i would want that to happen OR i would want stuff working like eyefinity but as you know eyefinity is only for hd5000 family upwards -.-'
Thanks for the answer

Comment: My bad, I added an edit after further research.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Top Bottom  Extended

Stretched out MS paint program, with 1920x1080 pic zoomed

[image]

video card ATI 4890 Dvi connections.  no eyefinity, windows 7 , works similar in XP

Side By Side Extended

[image]

XNview streteched out across the 2 monitors

[image]

for Walpapers you just make a double size image, and use the TILE option.

For videos, you just have to have the correct display mode, because overlays wont work on both monitors.

For things being different sizes on one monitor vrses the other, the monitors need to be the same size (these are not exactly) and the resolution needs to be set similar.

For everything else you need some sort of Software as Surfasb Pointed out.

the Gap is not adjustable, wheras on eyefinity you can leave a hole, where the bezels are, as soon as someone gets rid of the bezels altogether I will care :-)  Neither missing parts or bezels impress me much, so I still would not game that way.

Comment: That is streching one program or image to two monitors instead of stretching the output that fits one monitor to fit two monitors. But thanks for the help. I've edited my question

Comment: @wxiiir  Well your comment here confirms better what you were asking.  First you want GAMES to Seamlessly hop to 2 monitors, some games do work with 2 without eyefinity, although I have not seen that happen here. You want the One Whole Resolution to be across what is double that resolution in monitors. It sort of doesnt ever really happen that way, but the res on both (lowered) and eyefinity monitors on low res can  be like that.  If I had 3 monitors I might care more myself, Because having any Split right down the most central part of movies and games wont work for me. Everything is centered

Comment: Something has to give, to do what your asking. take the example of 2 1080 HD monitors,  either a 1920x1080 image is Interpolated to the 2 monitors, and it looks worse than using one monitor closer.  or a  3840x1080 image is put to both monitors , which takes 2x power to render.   Or a 2400x 1080 type of image is tossed to the 2 monitors with the monitors interpolating across thier resolutions.

Comment: yes i know something has to give, i just want to know how to do it, it's just that simple. Thank you for your answers nonetheless